# Does strategy always needs to be passed from the client code in Strategy Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern, strategy-pattern

I have below piece of code:

```
public interface SearchAlgo { public Items search(); }

public class FirstSearchAlgo implements SearchAlgo { public Items search() {...} }

public class SecondSearchAlgo implements SearchAlgo { public Items search() {...} }
```

I also have a factory to create instances of above concrete classes based on client's input. Below `SearchAlgoFactory` code is just for the context.

```
public class SearchAlgoFactory {
   ...

   public SearchAlgo getSearchInstance(String arg) {
      if (arg == "First") return new FirstSearchAlgo();
      if (arg == "Second") return new SecondSearchAlgo();
   }

}
```

Now, I have a class that takes input from client, get the Algo from Factory and executes it.

```
public class Manager{
 
   public Items execute(String arg) {
      
        SearchAlgo algo = SearchAlgoFactory.getSearchInstance(arg);
        return algo.search();
   }

}
```

Question:

I feel that I am using both Factory and Strategy pattern but I am not sure 'cause whatever examples I have seen they all have a `Context` class to execute the strategy and client provides the strategy which they want to use. So, is this a correct implementation of Strategy?

Comment: The Strategy pattern utilizes composition, and since there is no composition relationship in this example, it is technically not a Strategy. Also note the Factory here is not a GoF pattern either. Head First Design calls this a Simple Factory.

Answer (score 1):

If it comes to implementing design patterns, it is much more important to understand what they do than to conform to some gold standard reference implementation. And it looks like you understand the strategy pattern.

The important thing about strategies is that the implementation is external to some client code (usually called the context) and that it can be changed at runtime. This *can* be done by letting the user provide the strategy object directly. However, introducing another level of indirection through your factory is just as viable. Your `Manager` class acts as the context you see in most UML diagrams.

So, yes. In my opinion, your code implements the strategy pattern.